# Service Fabric deployment hanging on GetApplicationExistence

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-service-fabric

I have created a Service Fabric cluster in Azure from scratch, with security provided by an X509 certificate. There is one node type with five nodes, all of which appear healthy when I look in Service Fabric Explorer.

I have a solution in Visual Studio 2017 (v15.3.5) containing a Service Fabric project along with one other project which is a Stateless Service. When I attempt to deploy this, I select the cluster in the publish window, and hit go.

It then sits indefinately displaying "Started executing script 'GetApplicationExistence'" in the Build output window in VS. No amount of waiting will result in either success nor an error message. I can't find anything in the logs in Azure.

Does anyone have any idea what could be going wrong?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I am facing similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your LocalCluster is healthy. There should not be any error/warning. I had warning System/DnsService was not up.

Reset the LocalCluster worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that there was something wrong with my development environment; the service fabric installation had got messed up somehow. When I tried with the exact same code from a different machine it all worked properly. I updated the Service Fabric elements of Visual Studio to the latest version and all started working again.